# Android Button onClick start ViewFlipper's child

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, viewflipper

Im newbie in Android and I was wondering how to start ViewFlipper in another Activity on specific child, I want this button to start another Activity in ViewFlipper in specific child

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

    final ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,
                    Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

activity 2:

```
private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
private float lastX;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper);
}

// Using the following method, we will handle all screen swaps.
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        lastX = touchevent.getX();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        float currentX = touchevent.getX();

        // Handling right to left screen swap.
        if (lastX < currentX) {

            // If there aren't any other children, just break.
            if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                break;

            // Next screen comes in from left.
            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_right);
            // Current screen goes out from right.
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);

            // Display next screen.
            viewFlipper.showNext();
        }

        // Handling left to right screen swap.
        if (lastX > currentX) {

            // If there is a child (to the right), just break.
            if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
                break;

            // Next screen comes in from right.
            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_left);
            // Current screen goes out from left.
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);

            // Display previous screen.
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So how can I tell the first activity to start the second activity in specific child like, button1 start child 2 and button2 start child 10

Answer (score 0):

As i right understand this code will be useful

Your another activity

In onCreate() method

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);
ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);
```

another activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="#00ff00">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="first" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ff0000" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="second" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

To start another activity use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks but you didn't understand what I mean, I know this but what I dont know is how to start directly the viewflipper in specific child, like start viewflipper in the second linearlayout and I can scroll it after that

Comment: if viewflipper exists in current activity layout. No matter where you put it) Simply you can use findviewbyid to call it

Comment: i will add my question to make you understand :D what i want, wait please

Comment: sorry but in my opinion it is impossible what do you want

Comment: why don't to do all in current activity? if you want to have separate layouts only then use fragments

Comment: if it right, so how can I make an app that show images and I can move it like ViewFlipper and I can select from a button the image that i want to show it and move after when I want to the next image with viewflipper

Comment: i remember suddenly it is impossible may be) by using activity but possible using fragmentactivity. Recently i use it. In fragmentactivity you can do things like in usual activity

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Comment: Good luck! i used this for viewpage which holds gridview. It is rather simple

Comment: ok thank you, but with this, can we make an option to save the child that we want to back to him after shutting down the app

Comment: To be honest i use class which extends fragment and class which extends fragmentpageradapter. What is for about fragmentactivity it is my suppose) But it should work